How do I report a phone number and email address that I do not own and is preventing me from adding a new account to my Gmail?
I'm trying to add a new Gmail address to my Google Gmail. After entering the Gmail address, I'm prompted to enter password of course. When I click on "forgot password" , I'm being offered a verification code to be sent to my phone number or an existing Gmail address both of which I do not own and I cannot identify.
